# Capture Hebrew keystrokes in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-events

I try to handle keystrokes, specifically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+char, by using the JQuery keydown event:
http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

This works OK for Latin chars (for example, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> results in an event with "ctrlKey:true", and "which:66").

However, when I change my keyboard layout to Hebrew, and press the same keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>נ</kbd> in this example), I get "which:0", keyCode and charCode are also 0, so I cannot detect which key exactly was pressed.

This is very annoying to my users, as they type in Hebrew, and must change their layout to English each time they want to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+something.

I am sure it is possible to capture Hebrew keystrokes, since in the GMail editor (for example), I can click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in both English and Hebrew layouts, and get the same results.

System Information: Ubuntu 12.04, Firefox 14. (Note: in Chrome I do get the correct keycode).

Comment: Hmm...I'm wondering if maybe you need to change the charset to hebrew. Have you tried doing `charset="Windows-1255"` and seeing if it changes anything?

Comment: My charset is UTF-8 because my database is UTF-8... I'm don't want to use other encodings because I'm afraid it will do a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I found it - just use the "keypress" event instead.